# Method not allowed. error on AjaxEnabledSCFService

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, telerik-grid

I have a RadGrid in my ASP.Net web form.
Now i want to bind this on client-side through a AjaxEnabledWCFService.
After all the implementations done it seems the data is being retrieved through the response
but rather than showing it in the grid it shows an messge like "Method not allowed.".

I could not able to find the actual reason behind this error, and what is the cause for dat not being populated.

Here are the details of my implementations :-
I have added the particular service to the Script manager like below :-

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
         <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/services/CustomerListService.svc" />
         </Services>
        <Scripts>
            <%--Needed for JavaScript IntelliSense in VS2010--%>
            <%--For VS2008 replace RadScriptManager with ScriptManager--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

Then added the service to the RadGrid ClientEvents - DataBindings tag like below :-

```
 <DataBinding SelectMethod="GetCustomers" Location="~/services/CustomerListService.svc" 
                     SortParameterType="Linq" FilterParameterType="Linq">
                </DataBinding>
```

I have a service named orderListService with DataContract as order,
ServiceContract as GetCustomers() as below codes :-

Ex:

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class CustomerListService
{

```
[OperationContract]
public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    CustomerData CustData = new CustomerData();
    System.Data.DataTable dt = CustData.GetCustomersList(1, 1, "");

    List<Customer> Customerist = new List<Customer>();//Here Customer is DataContract
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        SetPropertiesFromOrderRow(cust, dr);//set all the property values from DataRow to Order
        CustomerList.Add(cust);
    }

    return CustomerList;
}
```

}

The settings in the configuration file are like below :-

```
   <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientSideBindingTest.services.CustomerListServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
     <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>

  <services>
   <service name="ClientSideBindingTest.services.CustomerListService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ClientSideBindingTest.services.CustomerListServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
     binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ClientSideBindingTest.services.CustomerListService" />
   </service>
  </services>
```

Please let me know if anyone having any suggestions here and also i need to know how to pass the parameter to the service method to 
get the values as per the parameter supplied.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my question here is the details described below :-

Reason : The main reason behind this "Method not allowed." could be caught after i enabled the tracing feature of the WCF by setting the configuration in the web.config file.
What it traced i am describing here :-

Description : I had a DateTime type field when i was assigning value from DB to this field NULL values are avoided to be assigned so for the fields not assigned a default value of '01/01/0001 00:00:000' is being automatically assigned to the field. But when this field is being passed to the jSon this date is the out of range of the json Date fields, which is causing the actual error here and it throws that exception and service breaks there.

Solution :  The solution is simple, just i needed to make the DateTime field as Nullable so that it will take the NULL rather than assigning a default out of range value to the field and this fixed my issue. Thanks to WCF tracing facility which helped me to track the exact error.